# Remote Desktop Connection over VPN on mac

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, vpn

I'm trying to connect to a Windows computer on over a VPN connection using Remote Desktop connection. I opened Network on mac and created a new connection.

Interface: VPN. VPN Type: PPTP.

I filled the inputs for server address, account name, password and applied. I connect the VPN and it connects. I open Remote Desktop Connection and put the IP of the machina i want to connect but it dont connect, a problem occurs saying that the machina may be turned off and etc. But in a windows machine I can connect there and the machine is up and running. On my mac I ping to the ip address that a want to connect and it has no response.

I think that the vpn have a problem, is there a way for me to certificate that i am on the vpn network ? Whats going on?

Comment: Can you ping the Windows machine when you have the VPN connection established?  What version of OSX?

Comment: no, the ping has no response. I am using Mountain Lion.

Comment: That might be part of your problem.  What is the subnet of your VPN connection and of your Windows machine?

Comment: My TCP/IP its configured with "Using PPP", the ip that it is getting is 10.10.3.8 and the ip of windows machine is 172.16.0.80

Comment: So it looks like there is no route between the two networks?  You could add in the routes by hand if you know the right gateways between the networks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is another solution:
Open System configuration, then Network. Please take a look to the list of connection you may have at your left side column. Be sure that VPN connection appears on top. If not, you may have to change clicking beside the +- configuration button. Find the VPN connection and drug to the top. Click Accept and try again to connect RDP

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Change your home router's network address rnage to something different from the VPN's network range. you can change it by typing in the router's IP address in the browser.

EDIT: I'm not an expert on this topic but the following is my understanding of the problem. 
The problem might be because your home router's network range is conflicting with the VPN's range. that is, if your home router and VPN might be both using 192.168.0.1~255 as the network range. It doesn't seem to cause problem when connecting from windows. However, when connecting from a mac it does.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your answer and describe why this is an effective solution?

Comment: @MaQleod updated the answer.